# What is the structure of the Nucleus?

Tags: atoms

The structure of an atom is well known to me as something like this:

[image: Structure of atom]

But what is the accurate structure of the **Nucleus** ? What is the arrangement of the *Protons* and the *Neutrons* or any of the other nucleons? I will be glad if anybody give an image of its structure.

Thanks!

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered on Physics.SE (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36469/are-the-protons-and-neutrons-in-the-nucleus-arranged-in-any-particular-way).

Comment: @Philipp I think question asked in other in S.E. is not considered as duplicate.

Comment: @Philipp Didn't get a good answer from there

Comment: @NeilRoy Have you also checked out the other content on that matter that can be found on Physics.SE, e.g. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/what-does-a-nucleus-look-like?rq=1)? If your question doesn't get a satisfactory answer on Physics.SE it is unlikely that you get a better one here, because your question is purely about physics not chemistry. Chemistry is concerned with molecules not with nuclei on a subatomic level. Maybe you could ask for clarification on Physics.SE.

Comment: @NeilRoy I'd suggest following some of the links in the Physics.SE question, including the ["liquid drop model"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula)

Comment: @Freddy I gave it only as an example. There are also other similar questions there that all revolve around this topic and which might provide at least enough of an answer to get by.

Answer (score 1):

> The nucleus is the very dense region consisting of protons and neutrons at the center of an atom.
>
> The diameter of the nucleus is in the range of 1.75 fm ($1.75×10^{−15}$ m) for hydrogen (the diameter of a single proton)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SslzL.png) to about 15 fm for the heaviest atoms, such as uranium. These dimensions are much smaller than the diameter of the atom itself (nucleus + electron cloud), by a factor of about 23,000 (uranium) to about 145,000 (hydrogen)
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Source:[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_nucleus)

Comment: I wanted the accurate description of the nucleus with all the nucleons in it. Is it possible please?

Comment: @NeilRoy Yes it is possible, but me I think it would be better some expert answer this question because I have just heard of stuff(quarks, etc) not read anywhere.